# Rails 5 - static index.html in public folder does not display the background image on production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, production

I build a Rails 5 app where the index page is static and inside the public folder.
I have a controller which does this:

```
render :file => 'public/index.html'
```

The router routes to:

```
get 'welcome/index'
root 'welcome#index'
```

In my inline css I added this:`

```
background-image: url('images/logo.jpg');
```

On stackoverflow there are some topics already about not displayed but all answers did not help. Very soon I want to have a simple Responsive Website located in the public folder. So the problem will a bigger one later I guess.

So the question is, how do I turn on the image display/rendering on production. Or do I go a complete wrong way and have to use the asset pipeline?

Comment: provide a link of jsfiddle?

Comment: What do you see when you go to the page?  Are you deploying on Heroku?  what does your config look like?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is because of [Asset Fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) that happens on production.

In your CSS ->

```
background-image: image-url('images/logo.jpg');
```

Change the image to use the scss/sass helper `image-url`

More information in the [docs](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails).